# Getting 403 when I docker login epregistry.azurecr.io from vs code

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, dockerfile

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1cG1FRjFOQ and it uses the password from the registry in Azure to login. However, when I try to login running the command `docker login epregistry.azurecr.io` it gives me the following error  `Error response from daemon: Get "https://epregistry.azurecr.io/v2/": error parsing HTTP 403  response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""`. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think this ACR login server doesn't exist or has been deleted.

I reproduced with my ACR and can log in correctly.

So after I deleted ACR and tried to log in again, I got the same error. (But it is `HTTP 404`)

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://<My-ACR>.azurecr.io": error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""`

Comment: I was able to login with the correct ACR name. I was inputting the wrong name before.

Comment: Great. If you could provide some detail that was fixed by your solution, it'll be great.